# Dependent list without the same value

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to make one list dependent on the other using javascript, but the value of the second is the value of the first list plus its own id, separeated by "*". I've been trying to split the value and get only the first part, but it returns nothing. What's wrong with the code?

```
listaversao = _context.Versao.Select(v => new SelectListItem
{
   Value = v.idLinguagem.ToString() + "*" + v.idVersao.ToString(),
   Text = v.nmVersao //this one depends on listaling, but it has two ids separated by the *;
});

listaling = _context.Linguagem.Select(l => new SelectListItem
{
  Value = l.idLinguagem.ToString(),
  Text = l.nmLinguagem
});
```

Javascript:

```
    var $linguagem = $('#lingua'), 
    $versao = $('#versao'),
    $options = $versao.find('option');

$linguagem.change(function () {
    $('#versao option')
        .hide() // hide all
        .filter(versao => versao.val().split("*")[0] == $linguagem.val()) // splits the val and filter options with required value
        .show(); // and show them
});
```

And that's how I'm setting the binding:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listaversao { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listaling { get; set; }
[BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
public string[] selecaover { get; set; }
```

And the html:

```
<label asp-for="Scripts.idLinguagem" class="control-label"></label>
<br />
<select onchange="mudar()" id="lingua" asp-for="linguagem" asp-items="Model.listaling"></select>
<select id="versa" size="10" onclick="mostrarv()" multiple="multiple" asp-for="selecaover" asp-items="Model.listaversao"></select>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in your console?

Comment: No, there's just no list when I choose an option in the first selection.

Comment: How are you binding the View(select list)?

Comment: Question edited with the information.